# if I have concentrated acetic acid (99%) what are the out put gases during electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

If I use concentrated acetic acid (glacial acetic acid($\ce{CH3COOH}$)) as an electrolyte. What ions are produced at the anode and cathode?

Can I get ethanol with it ($\ce{C2H6O}$)? If not, what would be the products?

Comment: I´m sure you can tell what *one* product is. As for the other electrode, what is the primary product, when you have abstracted one electron? The second intermediate should then be equally obvious, if you know a bit about organic chemisty. And the third and final is then trivial. ;)

Comment: And btw., this is a well known named reaktion. Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon electrolysis, organic acids will lose the carboxyl group and dimerize.
This is known as the Kolbe electrolysis:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolbe_electrolysis

In the case of electrolysis of acetic acid, ethane and $\ce{CO2}$ will be formed.